# I transfered money to Bitcoin Core wallet. Now, how can I use?

Tags: bitcoin-core

If I understand it right, I won't be able to use it till the BitCoin Core finish synchronising.

Is there anything I can do to use the money now? From the sender site transaction was completed succesfully: https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/address/1CQcKeg9L4zAkNhVaKMntS9kTY8n1rpcqA

And I'm always out of disk space because of sychnhronisng.

1CQcKeg9L4zAkNhVaKMntS9kTY8n1rpcqA

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin SE! Just as a quick thought: If you are fairly knowledgable in IT, then you can search on how to extract the priv key from your core wallet, load it into an Electrum wallet, and go from there. If you are new into this crypto world, then you definetly want to read a lot (e.g. Andreas' book "Mastering Bitcoin"), and start the adventure from there:-)

Answer (score 1):

You've just stepped into one of the worst problems with Bitcoin. The "default wallet", Bitcoin Core, is not for beginners.

You'll probably want to use a different wallet instead. The problem is that you've already sent a payment to your Bitcoin Core Wallet.

To recover your funds, you'll need to take a crash course in Bitcoin internals.

Your Core wallet contains private keys. You can move private keys from one wallet to another, although this is really bad practice and should only be used when nothing else will work. This might be one of those times, depending on how much money is at stake and how unwilling you might be to let Bitcoin Core continue syncing for the next several days, but as you mentioned you're running out space so it will never complete.

You sent funds to an address (a long sequence of text beginning with "1").

To get the private key for your address, get to the Core console (Help->Debug window).

Next, click on the "Console" tab. There is a text box at the bottom with a ">" symbol and a blinking cursor.

Enter this into the box:

```
dumpprivkey <address>
```

where `<address>` is your address.

From there, you have the private key (begins with "K" or "L", possibly "5"), which you can import into another wallet.

Elsewhere, you indicated you're using electrum. Here's how to "sweep" funds from your private key into Electrum:

http://bitzuma.com/posts/a-beginners-guide-to-the-electrum-bitcoin-wallet/#sweep-a-paper-wallet

Note that the article talks about a paper wallet, which is simply a private key printed on paper.

Comment: Where can I find the private key? And where am I moving the money?

Comment: dumpprivkey <address>, yo get your private key, you can sweep private key balance to any address using electrum, blockchain.info ..etc

Comment: Error: Please enter the wallet passphrase with walletpassphrase first. (code -13)

Comment: I don't remember which passphrase I set. Can I find it somewhere in files?

Comment: Can I find it somwhere in the files? Probably not, I guess. But what about backup files? Can they help? Which? And what can I do with them then?

Comment: if you have backed up your wallet.dat and it was unlocked so try with moving your current wallet.dat file somewhere else and paste your old wallet.dat file. else if you don't remember it forget about your bitcoins or you would ask another question.